# System default camera app not showing up

Tags: camera, app-icons

I am not able to find the system default camera app icon in menu on my GiONEE P5L handset (Android version 5.1). But the app is still on the phone and it's working as well. Able to take photos and videos. I want to show the icon in app menu. Someone please help me.

Comment: `Able to take photos and videos.`  and `not able to find the system default camera app icon in menu` . Then, how?

Comment: Able to open camera using notification toolbar shortcut

Comment: Check default camera in settings->apps. If camera app is found there, then its working well. Try with another launcher (Ex. Nova launcher) and check it.

Comment: Yes, the camera app is in settings > apps and it's working well as I said in my initial post. Ok I'll try with another launcher. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Open Google search and type "open camera"  then it will open

Comment: As I said camera is opening & working without any issue. But camera icon is missing. Please help me